# doxygen c++ : document privately inherited members exposed by the "using" declaration

Tags: c++, doxygen

As an example, I have the following classes:

```cpp
class A {
    public:
        void methodOne();
}

class B : private A {
    public:
        /** Brief description.
        */
        using A::methodOne;
}
```

I haven't yet found a way of forcing doxygen to pick up the documentation block.

As constraints I have many other doxygen-documented private members (from other classes as well) for which I don't want doxygen to process the documentation blocks, so **EXTRACT_PRIVATE** is not an option, even if using condition blocks like **\cond ... \endcond**.

I have found an [example](https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/28895546/) of something that may be helpful. It uses the **INPUT_FILTER** configuration variable to effectively target some marked private members and change their declaration to public before feeding the files to doxygen. Unfortunately this does not quite apply to my case because the method technically is already declared public.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes this is badly needed functionality, particularly for private inheritance.  For example if `class A` is a generic container its `operator[]` docs will relate to the container, while from the perspective of `class B` the `operator[]` documentation will describe much more.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem as well. One solution, though rather ugly, is to set the `PREDEFINED` option in the Doxyfile and use `#ifdef` preprocessor directives to actually add the member function to the derived class when Doxygen is generating the docs.

So, for example, with a Doxyfile containing:

```
PREDEFINED = _DOXYGEN_
```

The source could be defined as follows:

```
class A {
    public:
        void methodOne();
}

class B : private A {
    public:
        #ifdef _DOXYGEN_
        /** Brief description.
        */
        void methodOne();
        #endif
        using A::methodOne;
}
```

This sucks for several reasons, but the worst part is having to copy the function declaration from the base class, so if that declaration changes you'll need to remember to update the derived class documentation.

It's the only way I've thought of to document such declarations, since Doxygen doesn't support this capability.

Comment: Did you check whether or not there is an issue in the doxygen issue tracker? when not did / can you submit one? (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new).

Comment: @albert it appears to be essentially the same as [this one](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/3760). I believe the concept is the same whether it's a namespace or a class.