# Is it possible to add a private member-variable without increasing the containing object's size?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I've got a tiny little utility class called `ObjectCounter` that has no virtual methods and no member-variables; all it contains is a constructor and a destructor, which increment and decrement a global variable, respectively:

```
int _objectCount = 0;  // global

class ObjectCounter
{
public:
   ObjectCounter() {printf("DefaultCtor:  count=%i\n", ++_objectCount);}
   ~ObjectCounter() {printf("Dtor:  count=%i\n", --_objectCount);}
};
```

When I want to track the number of instances of another class that my program has created at any given time, I just add an `ObjectCounter` as a private-member-variable to that class:

```
class SomeUserClass
{
public:
   SomeUserClass() : _userData(0) {/* empty */}
   ~SomeUserClass() {/* empty */}

private:
   ObjectCounter _objectCounter;
   int64_t _userData;
};
```

(originally I would have that class subclass `ObjectCounter` instead, but doing it that way was making [my DOxygen class-graphs unnecessarily complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912340/how-to-exclude-a-class-from-the-doxygen-inheritance-graphs), so I changed to making it into a private member variable)

Today I noticed that adding this "empty" private member variable to my class objects often increases the sizeof the class objects (as reported by sizeof()).  For example, the following code shows that `sizeof(SomeUserClass)` increases from 8 to 16 on my machine when I include the `_objectCounter` member-variable:

```
int main(int, char **)
{
   SomeUserClass sc1;
   printf("sizeof(SomeUserClass)=%zu\n", sizeof(SomeUserClass));
   printf("sizeof(ObjectCounter)=%zu\n", sizeof(ObjectCounter));

   return 0;
}
```

The increase happens with or without optimizations enabled (via `-O3`).

I believe the reason for that is that the compiler is allocating space for the `_objectCounter` member-variable simply so that if some other code needs to get a pointer-to-ObjectCounter, a unique address can be supplied.  But no code in my program ever actually does reference the `_objectCounter` variable; it exists solely to execute its own default-constructor and destructor at the appropriate times.

Given that, is there any way to encourage (or better yet, force) the compiler to not allocate any space for this member-variable?

Comment: Try making the `int64_t` class member the first member of the class.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried it, `sizeof(SomeUserClass)` is still 16.

Comment: Inherit from `ObjectCounter` so that empty base optimization can apply. In most cases it will.

Comment: Tangential: It'd be simple enough to change `_objectCount` from a global variable to a static class variable belonging to `ObjectCounter`. Simple but requires more typing is changing it to respect the rule of 3/5/0 by adding copy and move constructors that also increment the counter as appropriate.

Comment: @Sopel that does work but see my third paragraph for why I'm trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: If you're using C++20 then there's attribute `[[no_unique_address]]`

Comment: side note, because `int _objectCount = 0;  // global` is global, [the identifier is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: I'm not too familiar with doxygen, but did you do private inheritence?  Some folks had trouble *exposing* documentation  from private bases.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/36421785/817643

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, private inheritance it was.

Comment: Does `#if __has_cpp_attribute(no_unique_address)` ... `#endif` say the C++20 feature is available?  As per: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use C++20, you can use the attribute [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) to accomplish this.  Using

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

int _objectCount = 0;  // global

class ObjectCounter
{
public:
   ObjectCounter() {printf("DefaultCtor:  count=%i\n", ++_objectCount);}
   ~ObjectCounter() {printf("Dtor:  count=%i\n", --_objectCount);}
};

class SomeUserClass
{
public:
   SomeUserClass() : _userData(0) {/* empty */}
   ~SomeUserClass() {/* empty */}

private:
   [[no_unique_address]] ObjectCounter _objectCounter;
   int64_t _userData;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   SomeUserClass sc1;
   printf("sizeof(SomeUserClass)=%zu\n", sizeof(SomeUserClass));
   printf("sizeof(ObjectCounter)=%zu\n", sizeof(ObjectCounter));

   return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
DefaultCtor:  count=1
sizeof(SomeUserClass)=8
sizeof(ObjectCounter)=1
Dtor:  count=0
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, except that when I try it (with `g++ -O3 temp.cpp -std=c++20`, using Apple clang v12.0.5 from XCode 12.5), `sizeof(SomeUserClass)` still gets printed as 16 even with the `[[no_unique_address]]` tag applied.  Compiler bug, perhaps?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Bug maybe, could not be implemented yet.  IIRC g++ on MacOS is actually clang, and at least clang 12.0 gives the correct result: https://godbolt.org/z/W5oaGG8vd

Comment: Ah, I see the difference -- if I declare `_userData` first, I get sizeof=16, but if I declare `_objectCounter` first, I get sizeof=8.